# Incomplete iffalse using xstring

Tags: macros, amsmath, xstring

I have a `macros.tex` included in the preamble that creates some <strike>useful</strike> dumb macros. I want to define a macro for writing fractions that adds a brace if the argument is longer than 1 character, what I have so far is:

```
\usepackage{xstrings}
\newcommand{\fracdivide}[3]{%
    \StrLen{#2}[\arglen]%
    \ifthenelse{\arglen > 1}
    {%
        \frac{#1\left(#2\right)}{#1#3}
    }%
    {%
        \frac{#1#2}{#1#3}
    }%
}
```

That produces the following error: 
`!Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 16`.

`line 16` is exactly the line where I have the `\StrLen` command. If I remove it (for example using `2` instead of `\arglen`), it compiles correctly.

Why do I get this error? And how do I solve it?

Here's a MWE, it seems related to the `\text` command of `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fracdivide}[3]{%
    \StrLen{#2}[\arglen]%
    \ifthenelse{\arglen > 1}
    {%
        \frac{#1\left(#2\right)}{#1#3}
    }%
    {%
        \frac{#1#2}{#1#3}
    }%
}
\newcommand{\partialdd}[2]{\fracdivide{\partial}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\ddt}[1]{\partialdd{#1}{t}}

\begin{document}
$\ddt{f^\text{big}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Make a complete example. One can't run tests with snippets.

Comment: I tried a couple of examples, but got no failure.

Comment: My best guess is something that's not fully-expandable is being passed as the second argument to `\fracdivide`. Possibly some other command from `xstrings`, but I've never used that package before.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you are right. I'm sorry. I uploaded a MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are better using `\noexpandargs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fracdivide}[3]{%
  \begingroup\noexpandarg
  \StrLen{#2}[\arglen]%
  \ifthenelse{\arglen > 1}
    {%
     \frac{#1(#2)}{#1#3}%
    }%
    {%
     \frac{#1#2}{#1#3}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\partialdd}[2]{\fracdivide{\partial}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\ddt}[1]{\partialdd{#1}{t}}

\begin{document}

\[
\ddt{f^{\mathrm{big}}} + \ddt{\Gamma}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I removed the useless (and harmful) `\left` and `\right`.

The problem is that commands such as `\mathrm` or `\text` won't survive the full expansion performed by default by `\StrLen`. With `\noexpandargs` this is avoided.

However, something like `\ddt{\vect{x}}` will be parenthesized. I don't think this is a really useful macro.

Probably a macro with a `*`-version is easier to work with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fracdivide}{smmm}{%
  \frac{#2\IfBooleanTF{#1}{(#3)}{#3}}{#2#4}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\partialdd}{smm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\fracdivide*}{\fracdivide}{\partial}{#2}{#3}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ddt}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\partialdd*}{\partialdd}{#2}{t}%
}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\ddt*{f^{\mathrm{big}}} + \ddt{f_1}
- \ddt{\vect{x}} + \ddt*{\vect{x}+\vect{y}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort! In fact I just realized that it puts braces in the situation you mention. Is there a way to strip all the "operators" acting on a argument to retrieve the actual length of the argument so that `\vect{x}` results in length of 1? Or also `\hat{\vect{x}}`?

Comment: @SolidSnake Not really, I'm afraid. Much better to specify yourself whether you want parentheses or not.

Comment: It's actually a dumb macro. :). I edited the question accordingly. And thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt at extracting the length of the string requires the argument to expand to a string. However, `f^\text{big}` does not. We can `\detokenize` the input:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,xstring}

\newcommand{\fracdivide}[3]{
    \StrLen{\detokenize{#2}}[\arglen]
    \ifnum\arglen>1
      \frac{#1\left(#2\right)}{#1#3}
    \else
      \frac{#1#2}{#1#3}
    \fi
}
\newcommand{\partialdd}[2]{\fracdivide{\partial}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\ddt}[1]{\partialdd{#1}{t}}

\begin{document}
$\ddt{f^\text{big}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This way `\fracdivide{d}{\alpha}{x}` will choose the parenthesized branch.

Comment: @egreg: Yes. Hopefully an edge case.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
\def\ddt#1{{\partial\maybebraces{#1}\over\partial t}}
\def\maybebraces#1{\maybebracesA#1&}
\def\maybebracesA#1#2&{\ifx&#2&#1\else\left(#1#2\right)\fi}


$$\ddt{f^{\rm big}} + \ddt{\Gamma}$$

\bye
```

In contrast to the other solutions here we do not mix the problem of construction of the fraction (with "partial" sign and with "t" in denominator) with the problem of "maybebraces". And (of course) no special packages (and no LaTeX) is explicitly needed.