# Problem with command expansion in xstring macro? "Incomplete \iffalse"

Tags: macros, expansion, fragile

I have written the following commands which first chunk the input text by `;` and then make "fractions" out of text that is separated by `/`. My intention with this is to display genotypes with propper formatting.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\genoLineDist{.2mm}
\newcommand{\genoSplit}[2]{%
    $\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \text{\protect#1} \\
    \noalign{\vskip\genoLineDist}
    \hline
    \noalign{\vskip\genoLineDist}
    \text{\protect#2}
    \end{array}$%
}

\newcommand{\geno}[1]{%
    \def\remainder{#1}%
    \def\splitchar{;}%
    \genoHelper
}
\newcommand{\genoHelper}{%
    \IfSubStr{\remainder}{\splitchar}{%
        \StrBefore{\remainder}{\splitchar}[\firstpart]%
        \StrBehind{\remainder}{\splitchar}[\remainder]%
        \genoSplitHelper
        \ifx\remainder\empty
        \else
        \ ;\ \genoHelper
        \fi
    }{%
        \def\firstpart{\remainder}%
        \genoSplitHelper
    }%
}
\newcommand{\genoSplitHelper}{%
    \IfSubStr{\firstpart}{/}{%
        \StrBefore{\firstpart}{/}[\upperGeno]%
        \StrBehind{\firstpart}{/}[\lowerGenoTemp]%
        \IfSubStr{\lowerGenoTemp}{\splitchar}{%
            \StrBefore{\lowerGenoTemp}{\splitchar}[\lowerGeno]%
            \StrBehind{\lowerGenoTemp}{\splitchar}[\remainder]%
        }{\def\lowerGeno{\lowerGenoTemp}}%
        \genoSplit{\upperGeno}{\lowerGeno}%
    }{%
        \firstpart\unskip%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

%working
\geno{y w ; ap$^{DG3}$ / CyO}
%breaks
%\geno{ y w ; ap\textsuperscript{DG3} / CyO}

\end{document}
```

Now by typing the following command in the document body

```
\geno{y w ; ap$^{DG3}$ / CyO}
```

We produce this output:

[image: genotype]

However, when I try to include any commands like `\textsuperscript`, or symbols like `\Male` or `\Female` anywhere in the input string, I run into the following error:

```
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line [line with \geno command].
```

My best guess is that I'm running into issues with argument expansion in one of the if statements, so I tried placing some `\protect`s in places I suspected could cause issues like when `\remainder` is first defined in the `\geno` command and the `\IfSubStr` to little success. I have also attempted to use the `\MakeRobust` command like so:

```
%definitions above here
\MakeRobust{\geno}
\MakeRobust{\genoHelper}
\MakeRobust{\genoSplitHelper}
```

But unfortunately the problem persisted.

Other blind shots in the dark include

- replacing the `\ifx` with `\if\relax\detokenize{\remainder}\relax` (same error)
- `\detokenize`ing the input to `\IfSubStr` (seems like they all return a false, might be doing something wrong?)
- Using various alternatives for the `\genoSplit` command (same error, I am now positive it is not the issue)
- Rewriting all commands to use `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand` (same error)

I have also found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374165/incomplete-iffalse-using-xstring), but I am not sure this is the same issue I'm experiencing, and the accepted answer (`\begingroup\noexpandarg [...] \endgroup`) prevents the macro from working.

I'm at my wit's end and would greatly appreciate some insight into what is causing this issue.

Comment: always provide a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry about that, I've updated the first codeblock to work as a complete example now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xstrings` doesn't like fragile commands in its arguments.

Here's an `expl3` implementation: first we split at semicolons; then each item is passed as argument to a function that produces the fake fraction, if `/` is present.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\genoLineDist{.2mm}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\geno}{m}
 {
  \tired_geno:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__tired_geno_parts_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__tired_geno_parts_out_seq
\seq_new:N \l__tired_geno_temp_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tired_geno:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tired_geno_parts_in_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__tired_geno_parts_out_seq \l__tired_geno_parts_in_seq
   {
    \__tired_geno_split:n { ##1 }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__tired_geno_parts_out_seq { \ ; \  }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__tired_geno_split:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tired_geno_temp_seq { / } { #1 }
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__tired_geno_temp_seq == 1 }
   {
    #1 % no /
   }
   {
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \seq_item:Nn \l__tired_geno_temp_seq { 1 } \\
    \noalign{\vskip\genoLineDist}
    \hline
    \noalign{\vskip\genoLineDist}
    \seq_item:Nn \l__tired_geno_temp_seq { 2 } \\ 
    \end{tabular}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\geno{y w ; ap$^{DG3}$ / CyO}

\geno{ y w ; ap\textsuperscript{DG3} / CyO}

\geno{y/w ; ap$^{DG3}$ / CyO}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect! expl3 seems really useful. Is there a resource you'd recommend to learn more about it, or should I just jump into the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Using only TeX primitive commands you can define your `\geno` macro like this:

```
\def\geno#1{\def\genoS{\def\genoS{; }}\genoA #1; \end; }
\def\genoA#1; {\ifx\end#1\else
      \genoS 
      \isinslash#1/\iffalse #1\else \genoB #1/\fi
      \expandafter\genoA
   \fi
} 
\def\genoB #1/#2/{$\displaystyle{\hbox{#1\unskip}\over\hbox{\ignorespaces#2\unskip}}$ }
\def\isinslash #1/#2\iffalse{\ifx/#2/} 

\geno{y w ; ap$^{DG3}$ / CyO ; next ; A/B}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might suffice, using `listofitems` parsing.  EDITED to handle the more general syntax specified by the author in the comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\geno[1]{%
  \setsepchar[&]{;&/}%
  \readlist*\myterm{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\myterm[]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt=1 \else \ ;\ \fi
    \ifnum\listlen\myterm[\zcnt]=1
      \myterm[\zcnt]%
    \else
      $\displaystyle
        \frac{\text{\myterm[\zcnt,1]}}{\text{\myterm[\zcnt,2]}}$%
    \fi
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\geno{y w ; ap$^{DG3}$ / CyO}

\bigskip
\geno{ y w ; ap\textsuperscript{DG3} / CyO}

\bigskip
\geno{ y w ; ap\textsuperscript{DG3} / CyO ;
   bp\textsuperscript{DG0} / CzO ; z x}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately it needs to display up to four different "list entries" that each should have the option to be a fraction, e.g. `oneA / oneB ; two ; threeA / threeB ; fourA / fourB` etc.

Comment: @tired63194 I have EDITED my answer to handle the more general situation you specify in your comment.